# P4Python: AttributeError: type object 'P4' has no attribute 'MergeData'

Tags: perforce, p4python

I am trying to create a P4.MergeData object to use with a resolver. I get this error (in title) when I do:

```
import P4
md = P4.MergeData()
```

How do I create this object? Or if I don't need to, how do I merge two files in general?

Answer (score 0):

Run the `p4 resolve` command, passing a `Resolver` object to `p4.run_resolve()`.  Your `P4Resolver`'s `resolve()` method will be called with a `MergeData` object that describes the resolve operation.

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4python/Content/P4Python/python.p4_resolver.html#Class_P4.Resolver